# pd.read_csv() imports list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

Goal: import one column .csv as a flattened list.

`ESG_BENEFITS.csv`:

```
import pandas pd

BENEFITS = pd.read_csv('../data/gri/ESG/ESG_BENEFITS.csv').values.tolist()

print(BENEFITS)
```

Output:

```
[['Accident insurance'], ['Adoption or fertility assistance programs'], ['Disability/invalidity insurance'], ['Mortgages and loans'], ['Pension plans/retirement provision'], ['Maternity and/or paternity leave'], ['Child care'], ['Job security initiatives for redeployment, including retraining, relocation, work-sharing and outplacement services'], ['Flexible workschemes and work-sharing'], ['Recall rights for laid-off employees'], ['Stock ownership'], ['Vacation'], ['Paid sick days'], ['PTO (including any of the following: unspecified, vacation and/or sick days)'], ['Insurance: Healthcare Employee'], ['Insurance: Healthcare Family'], ['Insurance: Healthcare Domestic Partner'], ['Insurance: Dental'], ['Insurance: Vision'], ['Insurance: AD&D'], ['Insurance: Short Term Disability'], ['Insurance: Long Term Disability'], ['Employee Assistance Program'], ['Education Benefits: Employee'], ['Education Benefits: Family'], ['Sabbatical Program'], ['Relocation Assistance'], ['Work/Life Support Program'], ['Wellness/Fitness Program'], ['Onsite Fitness Facilities'], ['Onsite Recreation Facilities'], ['Stock Options'], ['Stock Purchase Plan'], ['Employee Profit Sharing'], ['Retirement: Defined Benefit Plan (including pension plans)'], ['Childcare: Other'], ['Bereavement Leave'], ['Tuition reimbursement (other than career training)'], ['Gym facilities or gym fee reimbursement programs'], ['Higher education scholarship programs, for either employees or their relatives'], ['Preventative healthcare programs'], ['Flex scheduling'], ['Telecommuting options'], ['Public transportation subsidy'], ['Carpooling support programs'], ['Employee recognition programs'], ['Paid time off for employee volunteers'], ['Workforce training, skills, and leadership development programs'], ['Matching gift program'], ['Mentoring Program'], ['Others'], ['No additional benefits offered']]
```

**Desired Output:**
Flattened list, ignore extra spacing.

```
['Accident insurance'  ,   'Adoption or fertility assistance programs'  ,   'Disability/invalidity insurance'  ,   'Mortgages and loans'  ,   'Pension plans/retirement provision'  ,   'Maternity and/or paternity leave'  ,   'Child care'  ,   'Job security initiatives for redeployment, including retraining, relocation, work-sharing and outplacement services'  ,   'Flexible workschemes and work-sharing'  ,   'Recall rights for laid-off employees'  ,   'Stock ownership'  ,   'Vacation'  ,   'Paid sick days'  ,   'PTO (including any of the following: unspecified, vacation and/or sick days)'  ,   'Insurance: Healthcare Employee'  ,   'Insurance: Healthcare Family'  ,   'Insurance: Healthcare Domestic Partner'  ,   'Insurance: Dental'  ,   'Insurance: Vision'  ,   'Insurance: AD&D'  ,   'Insurance: Short Term Disability'  ,   'Insurance: Long Term Disability'  ,   'Employee Assistance Program'  ,   'Education Benefits: Employee'  ,   'Education Benefits: Family'  ,   'Sabbatical Program'  ,   'Relocation Assistance'  ,   'Work/Life Support Program'  ,   'Wellness/Fitness Program'  ,   'Onsite Fitness Facilities'  ,   'Onsite Recreation Facilities'  ,   'Stock Options'  ,   'Stock Purchase Plan'  ,   'Employee Profit Sharing'  ,   'Retirement: Defined Benefit Plan (including pension plans)'  ,   'Childcare: Other'  ,   'Bereavement Leave'  ,   'Tuition reimbursement (other than career training)'  ,   'Gym facilities or gym fee reimbursement programs'  ,   'Higher education scholarship programs, for either employees or their relatives'  ,   'Preventative healthcare programs'  ,   'Flex scheduling'  ,   'Telecommuting options'  ,   'Public transportation subsidy'  ,   'Carpooling support programs'  ,   'Employee recognition programs'  ,   'Paid time off for employee volunteers'  ,   'Workforce training, skills, and leadership development programs'  ,   'Matching gift program'  ,   'Mentoring Program'  ,   'Others'  ,   'No additional benefits offered']
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution is exported one column `DataFrame`, need export `Series` by select first column, e.g. by position with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
BENEFITS = pd.read_csv('../data/gri/ESG/ESG_BENEFITS.csv').iloc[:, 0].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Importing one column .csv as a flattened list.

```
from csv import reader
# read csv file as a list of lists
l = []
index = 0
with open('students.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    # Pass reader object to list() to get a list of lists
    list_of_rows = list(csv_reader)
    print(list_of_rows)
    for i in int(len(list_of_rows)):
        l.insert(index,list_of_rows[0][i])
        index+=1
print(l)
```

Comment: Awesome code. This is what I used to do, manually write code; but with Python there is always *"short-hand"* code that does it for us. I came from a Java/ C++ background is why